# How to format a number in ng:pluralize

Tags: angularjs

How to format a number passed into ng:pluralize directive via attribtute 'count'?

Consider following code:

```
<ng:pluralize count="5000000" when="{'other': '{} things'}"></pluralize>
```

the output is:

```
5000000 things
```

How can I modify this for output to be:

```
5,000,000 things    // in US locale
5 000 000 things    // in Czech locale
```

I tried using filter 'number', but I think I don't know where to put it. It doesn't work in the object passed to attribute 'when'. I tried these:

```
... when="{'many': '{{{}|number}} things'}"
... when="{'many': '{}|number things'}"
... when="{'many': '{|number} things'}"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to assign the value to a variable

```
 <ng:pluralize ng-init="myCount=5000000" count="myCount" when="{'other': '{{myCount|number}} things'}"></ng:pluralize>
```

This will format the value to the current locale rules

**Demo**:

- [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XvGHHmIuIgcqjIGgYVzp?p=preview)

Comment: So, in other words, you can't use the `{}` shorthand when you want to use a filter?

Comment: @RobKennedy here we're using a directive. Normally filters that have arguments can be used using {{expression | filter:filterArg1:filterArg2}} see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter

Comment: I understand that part. I'm asking about the `ngPluralize` feature in which occurrences of the two-character sequence `{}` in the `when` values get replaced with the `count` value. It seems that if we also want that value passed through a filter, then we can't just use `{}`; instead, we have to spell out `{{ expression | filter }}`. Have I missed something?

Comment: @RobKennedy let's continue this here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74589/how-to-format-a-number-in-ngpluralize

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Liviu T.'s answer, there's no real need to use ng-init to assign the variable. You can do it directly in count.

```
<ng:pluralize count="myCount=5000000" when="{'other': '{{myCount|number}} things'}"></ng:pluralize>
```